# Microsoft Reporting: Check if a certain value exist

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

Using Microsoft Reporting Services,  with local processing mode. Loading data sources and everything works nicely. What I would like, is to, in the the report definition, check if a certain value exist in on of the data sources. Is this possible? Like, if I have a data source with just one column of "Name". Can I somehow check if the name "John" exist among the loaded data?

The reason is that I would like to adjust some things if certain values exist. For example, if a certain value exist in that data, I would like to hide a column and adjust some widths etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an expression like this:

```
SUM(IIF(myData!Name.Value = "John", 1, 0))
```

You can put this in an invisible field somewhere, and then let the dynamic controls test on the value of the field.